# C++ : Size of the array didn't change even after deleting it

Tags: c++

Assuming I have this program below

The size of the array is 3 and basically when deleting it and then try to print the size again , I still get the value 3 .
Why is that ?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::vector<int*> v;
    v.push_back(new int{1});
    v.push_back(new int{2});
    v.push_back(new int{3});
    std::cout << v.size() << '\n';
    for (auto iptr : v){
        delete iptr;
    }
    std::cout << v.size() << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note, you're using pointers here and leaking memory because of it. Why not just use `vector<CPerson>` instead?

Comment: Why are you deleting elements in the array as you're iterating in something called `print()` not `print_and_mangle_pointers_beyond_repair_welcome_to_undefined_behaviour_town_population_you()`? You're not deleting from the array, you're deleting the allocations that the pointers in the array point to. In something like JavaScript, which you might be used to, `delete` removes things, but in C++ it just de-allocates memory.

Comment: Hint: If you want to remove things from a `std::vector` you need to use the appropriate "remove from vector" function, not `delete`. If you want to store pointers in there consider using a [pointer wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to manage memory for you.

Comment: This is far from being a minimal example. Does this short snippet cause you the same confusion? https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2eb0d62bf5d3441c

Comment: @alterigel Yea thanks I changed it

Comment: Why are people voting to close as "caused by typo"? it's not a typo but lack of understanding morelikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a vector of pointers. Using `delete` on a pointer in that vector will delete the thing the pointer is pointing at. It does not remove the pointer itself from the vector, and so does not change the size of the vector. Why should it? How could it?

Here the code you were looking for (I guess):

```
  for (int i = 0; i < Persons.size(); i++)
  {
    CPerson *Student = Persons[i];
    if (Student)
    {
      Persons.erase(Persons.begin() + i);
      delete Student;
      i--;
    }
  }
```

Note:

1. `vector::erase` is (one way) to remove items from a vector.
2. The cast is unnecessary, because your base class has a virtual destructor.
3. Erasing items from a vector while you are iterating through it is tricky because the size of the vector changes when you erase an item and all the later items in the vector move down one place, that why I have `i--` to compensate, without that you will at least skip items and at worst iterate off the end of the vector.

Comment: It deletes the resource being pointed to. The pointer is now dangling, and still very much there, hence the size of the vector not changing.

Answer (score 3):

Because you deleted whatever was pointed by the pointer

```
    vector<CPerson *> Persons;
```

As far as the vector is concerned, it still has 3 pointers pointing somewhere.
Beware, you are not permitted to dereference them pointers, otherwise you will invoke undefined behavior).

Comment: It's gone from having 3 valid pointers, to 3 invalidated pointers.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the pointers that are in the vector, it just deletes the memory that you assigned to them with `new`, it doesn't do anything about the fact that you have a pointer, there for you are cleaning up memory that is outside of the vector, the vector will clean it self up at the end of the scope. (In this case, the end of the function.) Just remember, the vector doesn't clean up your `new` memory, you have to clean that up.